Unable to save and access session data. Express server and Angular front end
I'm new to Express and Angular and this is my first time posting a question on SO. I'm working on an app in which I want to be able to maintain session data. Once a user is logged in I want to store their data in their session for access in future requests. Currently I'm able to send a cookie to the client but the client is unable to send it back. It seems each time a request is made a new session has to be created. The "user" attribute that was supposed to be saved when the user logged in is "undefined".
In express-session DEBUG shows:
express-session no SID sent, generating session
on each request even after the user has logged in and the cookie was saved in their browser
Screen shot of server console after logging in a user and then reloading the page:server console
I've tried just about every solution I could find on SO in respect to Express and Angular session problems.
Since the request is cross origin from port 4200 to 3000 I tried creating a proxy configuration for angular. I also set withCredentials=true for the calls to the express server from Angular
proxy.conf.json:
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        }
  }
}

angular httpclient calls to express server:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 

@Injectable({ 
    providedIn: 'root'
}) 
export class ApiService { 
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 
    getMessage() { 
        return this.http.get( 
            '/api' + '/api/message',{withCredentials:true, observe:'response'}); 
    } 
    signupUser(newUser:any){
        return this.http.post('/api' + '/api/signup',newUser,{withCredentials:true});
        
    }
    loginUser(loginUser:any){
        return this.http.post('/api' + '/api/login',loginUser,{withCredentials:true, observe:'response'});
    }
}

Where one of the calls to the api actually takes place:
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core'; 
import { ApiService } from './api.service'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@Component({ 
  selector: 'app-root', 
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', 
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] 
}) 
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
  title = 'client'; 
  message: any;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef) {
      
   }; 
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.apiService.getMessage().subscribe(data => { 
      console.log(data);
      this.message = data.body; 
    }); 
  } 
  signUpClick(){
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(SignupComponent);
  }
  loginClick(){
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(LoginComponent);
  }
}


I also set up cors on the Express server with credentials:true and origin:http://localhost:4200
server.js:
const express = require('express'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const hashword = require('./serverutil/hashword');
const session = require('express-session');
//const cookies = require('cookie-session');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const app = express(); 

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(cors( {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    credentials: true
} ));
app.use(session({
    secret:"testing",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    cookie:{sameSite:'lax',secure:false,maxAge:600000,httpOnly:true,name:"user"}
}));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/api/message', (req, res) => { 
    //console.log(req);
    console.log(req.session);
    console.log(req.session.user);
    const userData = req.session.user;
    if(authenticated){
        res.json({user:userData});
    }else{
        res.json({ message: 
            'Hello New User' });
    }
     
}); 

const User = mongoose.model('appuserreals',{
        username: String,
        password: String,
        email: String
    });
   

app.post('/api/signup',(req,res) =>{

    mongoose.connect("mongodb");
    let hashed = hashword.hashPassword(req.body.password);
    console.log(hashed);
    var new_user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: hashed,
        email: req.body.email
    })
    new_user.save().then(()=>{
        req.session.user = new_user;
        req.session.save();
        console.log("saved");
        res.json({message: "ADDED"});
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.json({message: "ERROR"});
    })
    

})
app.post('/api/login',async function(req,res){
    mongoose.connect("mongodb");
    user = await User.findOne({username:req.body.username}).exec();
    if(user){
        let compared = hashword.comparePassword(req.body.password,user.password);

        if(compared){
            req.session.user = user;
            req.session.save((err) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log("session save error", err);
                    res.sendStatus(500);
                }else{
                    res.json({message:"loggedin"});
                }
            });
            console.log(req.session.user);
            console.log('logged in');
            
        }else{
            console.log('wrong password for')
            res.json({message:"WRONGPASSWORD"});
        }
    }else{
        console.log('user not found');
        res.json({message:"USERNOTFOUND"});
    }
    
    
})

app.listen(3000, () => { 
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000'); 
});


I'm sure there's plenty of other things wrong with my current code but currently I'm focused on trying to be able to manipulate session data. Once I fix my session problem I will expand and refine the code from there.
